# Unhandled exception at 0x0f6cf9c4 in server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001

Tags: c

Here is the code I have written in visual studio 2008. I get data in Receive array & using that data, I am preparing response to it. But I get error "Unhandled exception at 0x0f6cf9c4 in server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001." every time at "strcat" function when code runs.

```
    byte Receive[50];
    unsigned char result[50]; 
    int index = 0;
    char *type;
    char *s =  "ff ff ff 1d 00 01 01 0b 00 01";
    char *s1 = "03 00 98 ac 06 36 6f 92";
    int i;


if (Receive[i] == 0x18)
    { 
        if ((Receive[i+1] == 0x20) || (Receive[i+1] == 0x21) || (Receive[i+1] == 0x22) || (Receive[i+1] == 0x23) || (Receive[i+1] == 0x24) || (Receive[i+1] == 0x25))
        { 
            if (Receive[i+2] == 0x00)
            {
                result[index] = Receive[i-4];`enter code here`
                result[index+1] = Receive[i-3];
                index = index+2;
                type = "report";
            }
        }
    }
}

index = 0;

if (type == "report")
{
        strcat(s, result[index]);
        strcat(s, result[index+1]);
        strcat(s, s1);
        strcat(s, array1[j]);
        strcat(s, array1[j+1]);
        strcat(s, array1[j+2]);
        strcat(s, array1[j+3]);
        strcat(s, array1[j+4]);
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you can't use `==` to compare strings. With `==` you compare the *pointers* only, not what they point to, and therefore it will never be true. Use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to compare strings.

Comment: As for your problem, start by running your program in a debugger to catch the crash "in action". That way you can locate where it happens in your code, and also examine variables and their values to make sure they seem fine. At the very least please edit your question to tell us where the crash happens and the values of involved variables.

Answer (score 1):

A likely candidate for the cause of the crashes though, is that you try to modify string literals.

When you do `strcat(s, ...)` you modify the string literal that `s` points to. A string literal is a read-only fixed-size array of characters terminated by the special character `'\0'`. When you use such a string literal as the destination in a `strcat` call you will first of all modify the read-only array, and then write out of bounds of the array. Both of these things leads to *undefined behavior*.

You need to create your own array, which is big enough to fit all the data you want to write to it. And don't forget the space for the string terminator.

*Furthermore* you use e.g. `result[index]` as a string. The elements in `result` are single characters, not pointers to strings. For this you need to use `strncat` to only concatenate a single characters. *And* you need to pass a *pointer* to the character. Depending on what `array1` is that might have similar problems.

---

As another possible solution you might want to use `sprintf` instead of a series of invalid `strcat` calls:

```
sprintf(dest, "%s%c%c%s%c%c%c%c%c",
        s,
        result[index],
        result[index+1],
        s1,
        array1[j],
        array1[j+1],
        array1[j+2],
        array1[j+3],
        array1[j+4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not    `strcat(s, result[index]);` because there is no memory alocated to `s` for holding the extra data concatenated to it, `s` has a fixed size..

Also, since probably is code is inside a function , `unsigned char result[50];` is local and not initialized to zero.so it's not a string and `strcant` can fail.

Same goes for `int i;` it's value is indeterminate so `Receive[i+1]` can fail.

fix to `unsigned char result[50] = 0;`  and `int i=0;`

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be related to declaration

char *s =  "ff ff ff 1d 00 01 01 0b 00 01";

This declaration will place value in read-only parts of the memory, and making s a pointer to that which makes any writing operation on this memory illegal.

When you are doing 
strcat(s, result[index]);

you are trying to write on read-only part of memory, which in turn gives you exception. You should allocate suffecient memory for s and then do string operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to trying to concatenate to a constant string (which would give you an access violation *writing* a location far different from zero), the source of your error is likely that you're passing single characters as second parameter to `strcat()`, instead of pointers. If you don't get at least a warning from the compiler in response to doing this, it means your compiler is badly set up.

And if you do get warnings but ignore them, it means your head is badly set up.